# Merge "transitive" and "intransitive" tags into "transitivity"

Tags: discussion, tags

I think we should merge [transitive](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transitive) and [intransitive](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intransitive) into a new tag, [transitivity](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transitivity).

Here's how we're using the tags right now:

- We have **15** questions tagged both [transitive](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transitive) and [intransitive](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intransitive).
- We have **7** questions tagged [transitive](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transitive) only.
- We have **6** questions tagged [intransitive](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intransitive) only.

Most of the questions that have only one tag or the other seem to be about transitivity in general, or are confused.  For example, [this intransitive-only question is really about transitive verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15553/how-do-you-use-%E6%95%99%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8B-%E3%81%8A%E3%81%9D%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8B)―the OP is making a common mistake, confusing transitivity with the phenomenon we see in verb pairs like 教わる・教える.  [This intransitive-only question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12734/it-seems-that-%E6%B8%A1%E3%82%8B-is-categorized-as-%E8%87%AA%E5%8B%95%E8%A9%9E-intransitive-verb-yet-it-is-frequently) is really about transitivity, and [this intransitive-only question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11839/how-do-i-interpret-the-japanese-construction-of-verbnoun) is about both transitive and intransitive verbs.

It seems like it'd be better in almost every case to merge them into one tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I merged the tags.

It's been about a week, and although there are only two upvotes, no one's objected, and jkerian agreed on chat that it was probably a good idea.